# How to call .Net Core dll methods from IronPython?

Tags: c#, python

I have created sample .Net Core dll (Platform: .Net Core 2.1 and tried 3.0 & 3.1 also) which contains single method (Say, Diplay()). I have installed IronPython 2.7.10rc1 (2.7.10.0100) and trying to call Display() using below steps:

```
import ctypes

a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('D:\\xxx1\\xxx2\\xxx3\\xxx4\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\xxx100.dll')

a.Display()
```

But I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 379, in __getattr__

  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 384, in __getitem__

AttributeError: function Display is not defined
```

Note:

Similar way, I have tried to call .Net Framework dll methods and it works fine.

In .Net Framework, I have declared "Display()" as External and after that I am able to invoke from IronPython.

Similar way I tried in .Net Core. But [DllExport ...] not available in .Net Core

Can anyone help me how can I call .Net Core dll method from IronPython 2.7.10 (Hope this is the latest one).

Regards,
Hari.

Comment: I'm not familiar to IronPython, but does `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()` offer information like *Was the loading successful?*

Comment: To run an application in Windows, you need a "main" entry point.  A class project does not have a main.  A console application or a windows form application have a main.  So I recommend you make your c# project a console application which creates a exe and call the exe from python.

Comment: ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() returns true. IronPython code is trying to execute Display() after successfully loading the library.

Comment: I do not think second point. Same flow works fine in .Net Framework where I am invoking dll method from IronPython code.